# Loading processed layers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, layers, qgis-processing, query

I am testing out Qgis (3.0) and have been unable to figure out how to reload a processed layer.

For example I have a simple attribute query from some land use zonings where land use = 'PR'.   The original query works great but when the project is saved and reopened, the results layer appears in the layers list but is empty.

Since it has been stored in the project (.qgs) file, I'm assuming there must be some way to rerun/reload/repopulate it without having to recreate the query each time, but I have obviously missed that.

Where should I be looking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably haven't specified an output location, which means qgis defaults to saving the outputs as temporary outputs only (e.g. in tmp folder or just in memory). You need to specify a location in order to make the results permanent.